# Быстро сформировать массивы позиций

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сформировать для каждого слова массив позиций? Например:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
m o s c o w   y e s    c  i  t  y     y  e  s

moscow: [0],
yes: [7, 16],
city: [11]
```

Желательно, чтобы работало за O(n)

---

Вот мое решение, но оно выглядит ужасно:

```
result = {}
for _ in range(int(input())):
    line = input()
    result[line] = {}
    pointer = 0
    word = ''
    for i in range(len(line)):
        if line[i] != ' ':
            word += line[i]
        else:
            try:
                result[line][word].append(pointer)
                word = ''
                pointer = i + 1
            except KeyError:
                result[line][word] = []
                result[line][word].append(pointer)
                word = ''
                pointer = i + 1
```

Как переписать лучше?

Comment: @MaxU Исправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял то так:

```
str_sample = 'moscow yes city yes'
lst_word = str_sample.split()

dictSearchWord = {}

for word in lst_word:
    if word in dictSearchWord:
        endIndex = dictSearchWord[word]['lstIndexWord'][-1] + len(word)

        dictSearchWord[word]['lstIndexWord'].append(str_sample[endIndex:].find(word)+endIndex)
    else:
        dictSearchWord[word] = {
            'lstIndexWord': [str_sample.find(word)]
        }
for word in dictSearchWord:
    print(word, dictSearchWord[word]['lstIndexWord'])
```

Выведет:

```
moscow [0]
yes [7, 16]
city [11]
```

Или другой способ:

```
str_sample = 'moscow yes city yes'

dictSearchWord = {}
word = ''
for ind, chars in enumerate(str_sample):
    if chars == ' ':
        print(word)
        if word not in dictSearchWord:
            dictSearchWord[word] = [ind-len(word)]
        else:
            dictSearchWord[word].append(ind-len(word))
        word = ''
    elif ind == len(str_sample)-1:
        word += chars
        if word not in dictSearchWord:
            dictSearchWord[word] = [ind+1-len(word)]
        else:
            dictSearchWord[word].append(ind+1-len(word))
    else:
        word += chars
```

Без **word**:

```
str_sample = 'moscow yes city yes'

dictSearchWord = {}
beginIndexWord = 0
for ind, chars in enumerate(str_sample):
    if chars == ' ':
        word = str_sample[beginIndexWord:ind]
        if word not in dictSearchWord:
            dictSearchWord[word] = [ind-len(word)]
        else:
            dictSearchWord[word].append(ind-len(word))
        beginIndexWord = ind+1
    elif ind == len(str_sample)-1:
        word = str_sample[beginIndexWord:]
        if word not in dictSearchWord:
            dictSearchWord[word] = [ind+1-len(word)]
        else:
            dictSearchWord[word].append(ind+1-len(word))
```

Comment: решение работает, но не за О(n) - на каждой итерации find O(n*m) + срезы O(k)

Comment: Добавил за один проход

Comment: Не нужно к word добавлять по букве, это портит асимптотику. Можно запомнить позицию последнего пробела, и после него будет начало слова.

Comment: Добавил без word

Answer (score 0):

можно с помощь регулярки сделать, но сложность О оценить затрудняюсь:

```
from re import finditer

str_sample = 'moscow yes city yes'
res = {}

for m in finditer(r'\w+', str_sample):
    res[m[0]] = res.get(m[0],[]) + [m.start()]
    
print(res)  # {'moscow': [0], 'yes': [7, 16], 'city': [11]}
```

Comment: `res[m[0]] = ...` - вот тут квадратичная сложность. Надо делать через `append`.